# Divide a list in the following manner

Tags: python, list

I have this list

```
list=[0,1,2,3,4,2,6]
```

I want to make another list of tuples like  this:

```
list=[(0,1),(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,2),(2,6)]
```

Is there a built-in function that i can use?

Comment: use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

Comment: Do not use list as a variable name, it shadows the built-int [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use zip and list comprehension. `listt[1:]` starts from the second element. This is done because in your first pair, you have the 1st and the 2nd element. `zip` creates pairs and then you iterate over them and use `()` to store them as tuples.

A piece of advice: Do not use builtin names as variables. `list` in your case.

```
listt=[0,1,2,3,4,2,6]

result = [(i) for i in zip(listt, listt[1:])]
# [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 2), (2, 6)]
```

**Benchmarking performance**

Based on @prashant rana's comment, I compared the performance of `zip` with his approach taking a list **1 million** times longer than the original list. Below are the results: `zip` turns out to be faster

```
import timeit
listt=[0,1,2,3,4,2,6]*1000000

%timeit [(listt[i],listt[i+1]) for i in range(len(listt)-1)]
%timeit [(i) for i in zip(listt, listt[1:])]

1.76 s ± 178 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
937 ms ± 46.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: using zip will make it slow .

Comment: Might be true but I am assuming the OP is not using it for production purposes. For small lists, like in the question, it serves the purpose

Comment: i find it's execution time twice the execution time of mine

Comment: @prashantrana: Check my edit for a list 1 million times larger than the original list. `zip` is faster than your method

Comment: yes `zip` really is more faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
[(i, list[idx + 1]) for idx, i in enumerate(list) if idx < len(list) - 1]
```

> [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 2), (2, 6)]

Answer (score 0):

There's no builtin function, but python makes it very easy to make your own. Here you go:

```
list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 6]
x = [(list[i], list[i+1]) for i in range(len(list)-1)]
```